# Configure Application Inisghts for Azure Function App (Terraform)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, terraform, azure-application-insights

using below snippet I can create application insights and function_app but I am not sure how to configure function-app to use the created application insights.

```
module "resource_group" {
  source      = "git::ssh://address"
  environment = "${var.environment}"
  application = "${var.application}"
  app_version = "${var.app_version}"
}

module "function_app" {
  source                            = "git::ssh://address"
  environment                       = "${var.environment}"
  application                       = "${var.application}"
  resource_group_name               = "${module.resource_group.name}"
  app_version                       = "${var.app_version}"
  app_service_plan_id               = "${module.app_service_plan.id}"
  storage_primary_connection_string = "${module.storage_account.primary_connection_string}"
}

resource "azurerm_application_insights" "application_insights" {
  name                = "${var.environment}-${var.application}-appInsights"
  location            = "${module.resource_group.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${module.resource_group.name}"
  application_type    = "Web"
}
```

but When I visit azure > function_app > Monitor, it still shows to configure application_insights.

[image: configure application insights]

any suggestion?

Comment: Please check answer for similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77226786/1176573).

Comment: Worth noting, web in ```application_type = "Web"``` shouldn't be capitalized.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See sample here: https://www.olivercoding.com/2018-06-24-terraform/.  You need to add the `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` to the `app_settings` of your function app.

### Update - 10/09/2023

Adding `application_insights_connection_string` and `application_insights_key` inside the `site_config` block is the new way. Terraform automatically sets up the `app_settings` map.

**Credit: [Rajesh Swarnkar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1176573/rajesh-swarnkar)**

Comment: is there a document for app_settings?

Comment: Documentation for App_setting can be found here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/function_app.html#app_settings

Comment: just to udate on this answer casing matters and should be "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"

Comment: I think, this has changed, using 0.12.6 I now go `app_settings =`: ` app_settings = { "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY" = "${azurerm_application_insights.appInsight.instrumentation_key}" }`

Comment: Adding `application_insights_connection_string` and `application_insights_key` inside the `site_config` block is the new way. Terraform automatically sets up the `app_settings` map.