# How to enable Application Insights using Terraform?

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

Using Terraform, how do you enable Application Insights agent-based monitoring for

Azure App Service (.NET Core 2.x)
Azure Function App (.NET Core 2.x)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To enable the Application Insights agent-based monitoring for Azure App Service (.NET Core 2.x) Azure Function App (.NET Core 2.x), you just need to add the environment variable for application insight in the app setting like below:

In Azure portal:

[image]

In terraform:

```
app_settings = {
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY" = "${azurerm_application_insights.example.instrumentation_key}"
  }
```

The result shows the logs for the function "functioninsighttest":

[image]

Comment: This appears to work for .NET Framework as well, as you might expect.

Comment: Here is the link to the Terraform documentation on how to create the azurerm_application_insights resource: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/application_insights.html

Comment: One thing to be cognizant of when using this method to add APP_SETTINGs to an App Service is that Terraform will clobber any existing APP_SETTING and replace it with whatever it's configured with. In some cases this may break your CI/CD workflow. Thus I would recommend if you want to access this value to use something like Key Vault 
 + Key Vault References; that allows Terraform to create the individual secrets (not whole APP_SETTINGs config) and therefore not erase existing config that could break your deployment.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently now in 2021 there are two ways to this.

The second one is:

```
app_settings = {
    "MSDEPLOY_RENAME_LOCKED_FILES"                    = "1"
    "WEBSITE_HEALTHCHECK_MAXPINGFAILURES"             = "10"
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"                          = "Development"
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"                  = azurerm_application_insights.appi1.instrumentation_key
    "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"           = azurerm_application_insights.appi1.connection_string
    "APPINSIGHTS_PROFILERFEATURE_VERSION"             = "1.0.0"
    "APPINSIGHTS_SNAPSHOTFEATURE_VERSION"             = "1.0.0"
    "ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION"      = "~2"
    "DiagnosticServices_EXTENSION_VERSION"            = "~3"
    "InstrumentationEngine_EXTENSION_VERSION"         = "disabled"
    "SnapshotDebugger_EXTENSION_VERSION"              = "disabled"
    "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_BaseExtensions" = "disabled"
    "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Java"           = "1"
    "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Mode"           = "recommended"
    "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_NodeJS"         = "1"
    "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_PreemptSdk"     = "disabled"
  }
```

Comment: What is the 1st way? And do we need to provide so much configuration?
"APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY" , "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"  these two alone will not configure the connection? @Maciek

Answer (score 1):

##### Documentation:

As of `terrform 3.75` (Sept.2023), the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_function_app) mentions:

> For application insight related settings, please use `application_insights_connection_string` and `application_insights_key`. Terraform will assign the value to the key `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` and `APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING` in app setting.

##### Solution:

Hence adding, `application_insights_connection_string` and `application_insights_key` inside the `site_config` block worked for me.

```
# App Insight is created with Workspace Mode 
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "law_fxapp" {
  name                = "appinsight-law"
  resource_group_name = ".."
  location            = ".."
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 365
}

resource "azurerm_application_insights" "app_insight_fxapp" {
  name = "appinsightfxapp"
  resource_group_name = ".."
  location = ".."
  workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.law_fxapp.id
  application_type    = "web"
}

resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "linux_function_app" {
  
  name                        = "linux-fx-app"
  resource_group_name         = ".."
  location                    = ".."
  storage_account_name        = ".."
  storage_account_access_key  = ".."
  service_plan_id             = ".."

  site_config {
     ..
     application_stack {..}
    application_insights_connection_string = "${azurerm_application_insights.app_insight_fxapp.connection_string}"
    application_insights_key = "${azurerm_application_insights.app_insight_fxapp.instrumentation_key}"
  }
}
```